# How to add a recent file with a .zip file extension, in a specified folder to a php variable?

Tags: php, search, variables, directory, zip

I would like to script in php code that will search a specific folder for a recently added file with a .zip file extension and add it to a variable to be manipulated later.

Answer (score 3):

Use [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to look for files in the specific folder, then isolate zip files using some strpos() or regexp on the retrieved filenames.
If needed, test the [last modification time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) of the zip files found.

Edit: Using [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) will even be faster to match *.zip files.

[Edit]
Managed to come up with this code but i think i coded dirty. Any way to clean this up?

`$show = 2; // Change to 0 for listing all found file types
$dir = ''; // Blank if the folder/directory to be scanned is the current one (with the script)

if($dir) chdir($dir);
$files = glob( '*.zip');
usort( $files, 'filemtime_compare' );

function filemtime_compare( $a, $b )
{
return filemtime( $b ) - filemtime( $a );
}

$i = 0;
foreach ( $files as $file )
{
++$i;
if ( $i == $show ) break;
$value = $file;
}
echo "This is the file name in the variable: " . $value;

?>`

Comment: Do you know how to use safe_glob()? I read a part that they will be retiring glob() and i wouldn't want to use a function that will seize to work all of a sudden.